# wso2 connection mysql jdbc

Tags: jdbc, wso2, api-manager

i tried to connect an mysql in api manager wso2 jdbc using this url `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eemp?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;useSSL=false`
but gets an error:

> The data source URL is not accepted by any of the loaded drivers.
> Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception:
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database
> URL, failed to parse the connection string near
> ';useSSL=false'.

Comment: Why do you have `&amp;` in the URL? Did you copy this from an XML file? Otherwise replace that `&amp;` with `&`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having the URL as follows.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;useSSL=false
```

Try the following

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```